# Problem in deleting a user

Tags: users

I m trying to delete a user. I was logged in from Root and tried a delete a existing user using userdel -r sammy(sammy is the user name) it is showing a error that the user is currently logged in but any other user exept of root is not logged in. How can i delete the user??

Comment: Please edit your question to provide the output of `w | grep sammy`. The user may also still have some files/sockets open. Verify that with `sudo lsof -n | grep sammy`. And I want to recommend using `deluser` over `userdel` as it is more high-level and easier to use (less likely to break things; similar to `adduser` vs. `useradd`).

Comment: does this command will stop all the files open of the user.??

Comment: No, I don't think so. I'm just saying that the user might still be owning some processes or file descriptors. But again, please provide the output so we/I can help you better.

Comment: i have created 1 more user and tried to delete that and that one is deleting properly.. but any user sammy is not deleting

Comment: Sorry, but your comment isn't helpful. Remember that we can't see your screen and we can't access your PC, so we rely on the information you provide in your question. By not providing the requested details, I have to downvote your question. And also please **edit** your question instead of posting additional information in comments. It's how this site works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sudo pkill -KILL -u {username}
sudo userdel {username}
sudo userdel -r {username}
```